# Configuring hadoop results in "/bin/java : no such file or directory"

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop on Cygwin.

I have set `JAVA_HOME` as follows:

```
\cygdrive\c\work\java\jdk1.6.0_30
```

in the file `conf/hadoop-env.sh`.

Performing a `echo $JAVA_HOME` also displays correctly

but the command `bin/hadoop version` gives the following error message:

```
/bin/java : no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

add this in `conf/hadoop-env.sh`

```
export JAVA_HOME="your java installation directory within this"
```